# Certificate verify failed SSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE

Tags: ssl, openssl, cpanel, apache2.4

I want to use SMTP service to send an email and a CURL service to verify google recaptcha. Both of those services throw error in production but work fine in localhost, that is because in production I have ssl installed on my website. I can disable ssl security and everything works but I don't want to disable SSL instead configure certificate to allow ssl based CURL and SMTP request.

I am trying to resolve below issue for past 2 days now:

```
Connection failed. stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. 
OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL 
routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

I get above error when submitting contact form. The form uses CURL, PhpMailer and SMTP protocol.

CURL and SMTP code both throws "certificate verify failed" error.

If I put below code, then CURL and SMTP no more throw error, but its a bad practice:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

and

```
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
  'ssl' => array(
      'verify_peer' => false,
      'verify_peer_name' => false,
      'allow_self_signed' => true,
  )
);
```

I am using CURL to verify google recaptcha

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

And SMTP code:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

//Set PHPMailer to use SMTP.
$mail->isSMTP();

//Set SMTP host name                          
$mail->Host = $_ENV['MAIL_HOST'];

//Set this to true if SMTP host requires authentication to send email
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;

//Provide username and password     
$mail->Username = $_ENV['MAIL_USERNAME'];
$mail->Password = $_ENV['MAIL_PASSWORD'];

//If SMTP requires TLS encryption then set it
$mail->SMTPSecure = $_ENV['MAIL_ENCRYPTION'];

//Set TCP port to connect to
$mail->Port = $_ENV['MAIL_PORT'];

$mail->From = $_POST['email'];
$mail->FromName = $_POST['name'];

$mail->addAddress($_ENV['MAIL_TO'], "Website Name");

$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = "Contact Form";
$mail->Body = <html>
$mail->send();
```

I have bought free 90 days ssl certificate, which had the "private key", "certificate" and "cabundle" files. I uploaded those files using cPanel "SSL/TLS Manager" to install new SSL. It was installed succcessfully.

And then I retrieved the CA file using the command below:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -servername <domain-name> -connect <domain-name>:443 > cacert.pem
```

I then put cacert.pem file to /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors

I ran:

```
update-ca-trust
```

When I ran `update-ca-trust` I get below:

```
p11-kit: overriding trust for anchor in blacklist: addtrust-external-root.p11-kit
p11-kit: overriding trust for anchor in blacklist: addtrust-external-root.p11-kit
p11-kit: overriding trust for anchor in blacklist: addtrust-external-root.p11-kit
p11-kit: overriding trust for anchor in blacklist: addtrust-external-root.p11-kit
p11-kit: overriding trust for anchor in blacklist: addtrust-external-root.p11-kit
```

I also put the file path in php.ini file (/usr/local/lib/php.ini)

```
curl.cainfo="/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/cacert.pem"
openssl.cafile="/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/cacert.pem"
```

but it does not seem to fix above error.

**Server details**

```
Centos 7
Php version: 5.6.33
Server version: Apache/2.4.29 (Unix)
Server built:   Jan 30 2018 10:32:28
Cpanel::Easy::Apache v3.34.21 rev9999
```

I also, tried several other solutions found on web but no success.

OPENSSL OUTPUT

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=3 C = BE, O = GlobalSign nv-sa, OU = Root CA, CN = GlobalSign Root CA
verify return:1
depth=2 C = US, O = Google Trust Services LLC, CN = GTS Root R1
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Google Trust Services LLC, CN = GTS CA 1C3
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = www.google.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/CN=www.google.com
   i:/C=US/O=Google Trust Services LLC/CN=GTS CA 1C3
 1 s:/C=US/O=Google Trust Services LLC/CN=GTS CA 1C3
   i:/C=US/O=Google Trust Services LLC/CN=GTS Root R1
 2 s:/C=US/O=Google Trust Services LLC/CN=GTS Root R1
   i:/C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/OU=Root CA/CN=GlobalSign Root CA
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/CN=www.google.com
issuer=/C=US/O=Google Trust Services LLC/CN=GTS CA 1C3
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Server Temp Key: ECDH, prime256v1, 256 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 4905 bytes and written 373 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
    Session-ID: 8A52A18E387F9631EE0AFA834011DDCF75482A903AE89C97D530E1A8B5E5DAE8
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: EAA26CCDCD2164763B4D9BCAE033767D992B004613E0C336F7881FC3144BDBC17863C35774BB423838B3FC91376937E7
    Key-Arg   : None
    Krb5 Principal: None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 100800 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - 02 92 85 e3 18 4d 5a c1-38 45 ac 34 7c ee a6 53   .....MZ.8E.4|..S
    0010 - d9 6c 8f 07 bb 03 6e 0d-d7 02 e6 a6 0a 26 af f8   .l....n......&..
    0020 - 3f 51 7b 15 28 fe 5a ac-ee 86 cf 28 b1 c9 04 6b   ?Q{.(.Z....(...k
    0030 - 75 c3 3c 40 19 2a c2 49-70 c4 3e 50 d2 24 7b c3   u.<@.*.Ip.>P.${.
    0040 - 8d a0 63 6e a6 c5 85 28-53 bd 5e 73 57 29 89 49   ..cn...(S.^sW).I
    0050 - 9b 42 f8 98 43 be 00 6b-6a af 83 64 a2 d5 ef 69   .B..C..kj..d...i
    0060 - cf 7d c1 2d 22 aa f9 b3-19 9e 65 fc a5 1d 72 51   .}.-".....e...rQ
    0070 - 6c 74 a8 26 49 12 ec a9-c1 6b 3b 72 e4 13 77 1e   lt.&I....k;r..w.
    0080 - 90 4e fe 3b 0a 8d 4e 0c-3a 3d 09 d8 2d 6c fa 20   .N.;..N.:=..-l. 
    0090 - 68 9f 0c 4a c5 28 7d e1-ff b4 5b 68 ae e9 7b 2f   h..J.(}...[h..{/
    00a0 - 4f 0e 2e 0b 06 8c 9b 18-f0 2f 7a ab 81 5a 15 bb   O......../z..Z..
    00b0 - 70 24 b4 ef 18 68 c4 33-72 cd 41 07 96 0a a3 6b   p$...h.3r.A....k
    00c0 - 27 4a 03 91 14 b5 03 c9-0b 73 e8 6d bc f2 6b 4e   'J.......s.m..kN
    00d0 - 0c 22 77 85 07 4c 48 52-12 eb 30 c2 fd e7 99 93   ."w..LHR..0.....

    Start Time: 1662466836
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
quit
HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
Content-Length: 1555
Date: Tue, 06 Sep 2022 12:20:41 GMT

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <title>Error 400 (Bad Request)!!1</title>
  <style>
    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}
  </style>
  <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
  <p><b>400.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
  <p>Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
read:errno=0
```

Comment: The server certificate retrieved by `openssl s_client ...` is not a CA certificate, i.e. cannot be used as trust anchor and `update-ca-trust` will not help.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich then where can I find or generate CA cert?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Can you share some steps or a link to a tutorial that I can follow. Thank you for the reply.

Comment: It is unclear for me what you are doing in the first place. What has the certificate for your own site to do with the code you show - is this for accessing your own site (in which the certificate for your site is relevant - and the CA for this is inside cabundle), is this for accessing something else **from** your own site (in which the certificates for your site are irrelevant but the certificates for the target site matter).

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I have a website which is https (ssl installed) and now when I submit a form, I trigger CURL and SMTP code, which throws SSL certificate verify failed error. In order to make CURL and SMTP ssl based request, I need to configure my server correctly.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I have put more info on what I am trying to do. I want to use SMTP service to send an email and a CURL service to verify google recaptcha. Both of those services throw error in production but work fine in localhost, that is because in production I have ssl installed on my website. I can disable ssl security and everything works but I don't want to disable SSL instead configure certificate to allow ssl based CURL and SMTP request.

Comment: The SSL on your website is about others accessing your site. This is totally unrelated to the SSL verification of the programs running on your website, accessing other sites. Likely your PHP is missing the relevant trust store or there is SSL interception done in your environment. Try `openssl s_client -connect www.google.com:443` on the server where you run this script and provide the output.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I have shared the openssl output as requested

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247818/discussion-between-steffen-ullrich-and-murlidhar-fichadia).